# What and where is this old-looking stone building?

Tags: europe, identify-this

[image]

can anyone tell me where this is located or what exactly it may be called?

Comment: Where did you find the picture?

Comment: FWIW Google images doesn't seem to know about it.

Comment: The general shape reminds me of monasteries in Armenia, Georgia, the Balkans.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I gave your post a more specific title, and added the tag [tag:identify-this] which we use for all questions of this kind.

Comment: @MichaelHampton A friend sent it to me but also cannot remember where he got it from

Comment: Did you friend take the pic himself?  If so, there may be meta data in the image that could help identify it.  I don't what the policy is here but the above image seems to have been stripped of meta data at some point.

Comment: @PeterM I asked something similar about researching the date, and other pictures taken around then but deleted it when I noticed the comment "A friend sent it to me but also cannot remember **where he got it from**" which implies the photo was not taken by him.

Comment: @WeatherVane There was still the possibility that this site scrubs meta data of uploaded pics - something that may not have happened to the OPs copy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This would seem to be the [Church of the Nativity of Jesus Christ in Chkondidi, Martvili Monastery](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Church_of_the_nativity_of_Jesus_Christ_in_Chkondidi._Martvili_monastery_(Photo_A._Muhranoff,_2011).jpg), in Georgia.

[image]
Picture by Aleksey Muhranoff (2011), Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported licence.

Comment: I'm curious to know ho you found this since google didn't know it.

Comment: An "Art Print of Martvili Monastery" is ca. 50 images down a Google Image search for "Georgian Monastery" looking pretty similar to OP's pic.

Comment: To be clear, this is in Georgia the country, not Georgia the US state, correct?

Comment: @Thunderforge I can't imagine any place in the US having the name *Chkondidi.*

Comment: Also, this church is far too old to be in the USA.